# Como desaparecer resultados que ya he mostrado de MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

de antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Actualmente he logrado traer los datos que tengo en una tabla en mi PhpMyAdmin, Tengo mi estructura creada en html y la veo perfectamente ordenada, ahora bien, quiero lograr que esos datos luego de asignarles un valor desaparezcan de mi vista pero no que se eliminen de mi base de datos.

actualmente tengo una tabla que trae lo siguiente:

Tabla pagos: Fecha - Monto - Comentario - Estado de Pago (menu Select > Aceptado - Anulado - Pago incompleto)

[image: estos son los datos y la estructura para que tengan una idea]

Ahora bien cuando seleccione en el Menú: Estado de Pago > Aceptado (y presione aceptar).... Desaparezca de la vista pero no que se elimine. Alguna idea en PHP o que más puedo utilizar para lograrlo? Saludos y gracias.

```html
<tr>
               
 <form class="form-group" action="modificar.php" method="post">
  <td>
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <select class="form-control form-control-line" name="estado" id="estado">
                                                                    <option disabled>Seleccione la entidad</option>
                                                                    <option>Verificando</option>
                                                                    <option>Pago Aceptado</option>
                                                                    <option>Pago Anulado</option>
                                                                    <option>Pago incompleto</option>                                                                                                                  
                                                                </select>
  </div>
</td>
                                                                                                         
<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Modificar</button></td>

 </form>    
</tr>
```

Comment: También yo quiero hacer lo mismo

Comment: Excelente bruno, esperemos que alguien nos guíe y nosotros hacemos el resto. Ahí vamos bro.

Comment: Claro, asi reforzamos

Comment: Saludos. ¿Que has probado? Sirve para hacer ajustes y/o sugerencias. Así mismo a los demás para sugerirte uso de librerias (por ejemplo yo jQuery -u otro-) que uses ya y te faciliten el ocultar el `<tr>` respectivo.

Comment: Normalmente esto se haría con un campo en tu tabla con ese valor (`Estatus`, para ejemplo), ese campo lo usarás como filtro, así, llamarás a todos tus registros con Estatus=`Incompleto`, y cuando el usuario haga clic en Aceptar, ese campo tienes que modificarlo a `Aceptado`. Como ya no es = `Incompleto` tu consulta no traerá ese registro.

Comment: Gracias por las dos sugerencias, voy afinando la idea de lo que se puede hacer, aun no he probado nada porque no encuentro hacerlo en concreto. Voy a modificar la pregunta y les dejo mi código.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tiene que hacer es eliminar esa fila de la tabla HTML del DOM, de esta manera te evitas hacer un nuevo pedido a la BD (igualmente en algún momento tienes que actualizar el estado en la BD, si no la próxima vez que muestres la página, volverán a aparecer).
Supongo por tu descripción que tienes algo así:

```
<tr id="fila_17">
  <td>17</td>
  <td>123</td>
  <td>19226523</td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>Pago Móvil</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>dasdadasdsd</td>
  <td><select>...</select></td>
</tr>
```

Acá lo importante es que tengas identificada cada fila (o elemento ) con un id único, que podría ser el id que ya estas usando y mostrando.
A c/u de tus select le agregas un event listener para cuando seleccionas una de las opciones (el argumento de la función lo puedes generar desde php, usando el mismo id):

```
<select onChange="javascript:borrarFila("17");">
  <option>Verificando</option>
  <option>Pago Aceptado</option>
  <option>Pago Anulado</option>
  <option>Pago Incompleto</option>
</select>
```

Luego creas una función en Javascript que busque el elemento  con id = 17, y elimine todos los contenidos. Usando JQuery sería algo así:

```
function borrarFila(id) {
   $("#fila_" + id).remove();
  
}
```

Eso sería más o menos todo, como no aclaras si usas algún framework, esto está hecho solo con Javascript y Jquery.

Comment: Hola, Alex, utilizo Bootstrap. Voy a analizar y restructurar tu código y les comento, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function ocultar(elBoton) {
  // Primero el TR que contiene todo que corresponde al boton pulsado
  var elTR = $(elBoton).closest('tr');
  // Con el TR buscamos el select y valor seleccionado
  var valSelect = $('select', elTR).val();
  // Obviamente necesitas saber con que valor o valores lo ocultaras si esta en el select; lo que sigue es ocultarlo
  // supongamos que solo cuando sea "3"
  if (valSelect=="3") $(elTR).hide();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3 select</th>
      <th>col4 boton</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>fila 1 col1</td>
      <td>fila 1 col2</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
          <option value="1">opcion 1</option>
          <option value="2">opcion 2</option>
          <option value="3">opcion 3</option>
          <option value="4">opcion 4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="modificar" onclick="ocultar(this)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fila 2 col1</td>
      <td>fila 2 col2</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
          <option value="1">opcion 1</option>
          <option value="2">opcion 2</option>
          <option value="3">opcion 3</option>
          <option value="4">opcion 4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="modificar" onclick="ocultar(this)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fila 3 col1</td>
      <td>fila 3 col2</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
          <option value="1">opcion 1</option>
          <option value="2">opcion 2</option>
          <option value="3">opcion 3</option>
          <option value="4">opcion 4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="modificar" onclick="ocultar(this)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```